# addClass/removeClass

Tags: jquery

{I want to be able to add a class to the body then remove that class and replace it with the new class on click of the 'a tag' html element, this is as far as I've got, adding the class, each click adds another class:

Can this be done by checking the a link for a class of selected instead of .click

html:

```
<ul id="dates">
<li><a href="#" class="selected">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul#dates li a.selected').bind(function() }
            var htmlStr = $(this).html();
            $('body').attr('class', htmlStr);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the class attribute entirely each time:

```
$('ul#dates li a').click(function() {
    var htmlStr = $(this).html();

    if( $(this).is('.selected') ) {
        $('body').attr('class', htmlStr);
    }
});
```

Comment: See my response; I'd use a `data-...` attribute.

Comment: you cannot do that, this grabs all html in the elements.

Comment: @ProgMania Yes that's what `.html()` does...and that's what the OP is trying to do, add the class "link1" to the body, or at least that's my understanding

Comment: Thanks that works. Can you tell me why the first class is applied to the body even before the click function?

Comment: @Rob It shouldn't be...are you calling `.click()` anywhere on any of your links by chance? Works for me, see if you can reproduce the problem in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u54t/)

Comment: Yes Ive got a click event part of the set of links I'm using. To elaborate this problem further can I add a class to the body element by searching if the active link has a class of "selected". So search for the class of that link and if it has the class of selected add the attr(class) to the body?

Comment: @Rob Yes you can. If you are calling `.click()` on the link that's why the class gets added to the body btw. As for your new requirement, update your question with your additional requirement and state exactly what you're trying to do...but see my update, hopefully it does what you want. It may be helpful to include your full html/js, and possibly a jsfiddle, and explain the effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @nbrooks Thanks, what I meant was identify if the link has a class of .selected and adjust(add a class to the body element just like before. This without the click event.

Comment: @Rob `.bind()` binds a handler to a *particular event*, such as a *click* event. If not onclick when do you want to check? On hover? As is your [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) is incorrect, it can't be used like that. You *need* an event type.

Comment: @nbrooks sorry i was just trying various events, I'm not sure, is there a way of checking to see if the class exists then if it does apply a function?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17492/discussion-between-nbrooks-and-rob)

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a `data-X` attribute on your body, instead of a class, e.g. `$('body').attr('data-clicked-link-html-string', htmlStr);`.

Answer (score 0):

you want the Jquery `toggleClass` method

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

```
if ($(this).is(".foo"))
{
   $(this).toggleClass("foo", false);
   $(this).toggleClass("bar", true);
}
else
{
   $(this).toggleClass("foo", true);
   $(this).toggleClass("bar", false");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#dates li a').click(function() {
        var htmlStr = $(this).text();
        $('body').attr('class', '').addClass(htmlStr);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

addclass method in jquery, uses a predefined class in your css, and only the class name is acceptable, 
var htmlStr = $(this).html();
this get the html like INNERHtml property grabs all html content in the element.
so you'd better declare a class like this:

```
.aClass {
float:left;
}
```

and in jquery do:

```
$('body').addClass('aClass');
```